# Price directly if condition is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

I'm working on an indicator that works with real-time candles and would like to display the current price directly on the candle in the form of a horizontal line if the condition is met. In addition, the direct price should be displayed in an alert.

I tried this but the current price is not displayed and output to the alert.

```
if (high_ > LL * (1 + PivotChg))             
alert("LL_Alert_"+ str.tostring(close) +" Long " + str.tostring(tick), alert.freq_once_per_bar)  
line.new(bar_index - 1, trade_preis_long, bar_index + 1, trade_preis_long, color = color.rgb(19, 80, 247, 0), width = 10)
```